# Neo4j: query to find 2 node with the most

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to find which pair of actors have acted together in most number of movies in my data base and my query kept returning blank, any suggestions?

```
MATCH (actor1:Actor)<-[st1:ACTED_IN]-(mv1:Movie)-[st2:ACTED_IN]->(actor2:Actor) 
RETURN distinct actor1,actor2,count(mv1)
```

Comment: Is this a sample movie graph that comes with Neo4j?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have written relationship arrows in reverse direction.

It might be from Actor to Movie:

```
MATCH (actor1:Actor)-[st1:ACTED_IN]->(mv1:Movie)<-[st2:ACTED_IN]-(actor2:Actor) 
RETURN distinct actor1, actor2, count(mv1)
```

Though you are using distinct your query will return duplicates because the following two are different records:

```
actor1, actor2, movie_count  
actor2, actor1, movie_count
```

To get rid of this duplicate entries you can use simple trick of comparing ids  of nodes like:

```
MATCH (actor1:Actor)-[:ACTED_IN]->(mv1:Movie)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(actor2:Actor) 
WHERE id(actor1)>id(actor2)
RETURN actor1,actor2,count(mv1)
```

**To find actors acted in most movies:**

```
MATCH (actor1:Actor)-[:ACTED_IN]->(mv1:Movie)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(actor2:Actor) 
WHERE id(actor1)>id(actor2)
RETURN actor1,actor2,count(mv1) AS movie_count 
ORDER BY movie_count DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: does this shows actors acted in most movies together?